# Creating trackbar changing brightness of image OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, trackbar

I've got a problem with creating a trackbar which would adjust brightness of the displayed picture.

This is my code (part which is involved with brightness):

```
int brightness_value = 25; //global values
const int max_value = 255;
int main()
{
Mat brightImage;
    srcImage.copyTo(brightImage);
    namedWindow("Bright Image");
    moveWindow("Bright Image", 300, 600);
    createTrackbar("Brightness", "Bright Image", &brightness_value, max_value);

    for (int i = 0; i < brightImage.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < brightImage.cols; j++)
        {
            Vec3b pixelColor;
            pixelColor = brightImage.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i));

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) //vector with 3 byte entries
            {
                if (pixelColor[k] + getTrackbarPos("Brightness", "Bright Image") > 255)
                    pixelColor[k] = 255;
                else
                    pixelColor[k] += getTrackbarPos("Brightness", "Bright Image");
                brightImage.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i)) = pixelColor;
            }
        }
    }
    imshow("Bright Image", brightImage);

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

This way the brightness of the image is adjusted only once, when the program starts. But when I want to change it with the trackbar nothing happens. Where is the problem, how should I do it so the brightness will change every time I move the trackbar?
Thanks for any help :)

And that's the result: (on the left original image, on the right with changed brightness)
[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createTrackbar` takes a pointer to callback function which is called when position of trackbar is being changed. In this callback you should redrawn your image with changed brightness level and refresh window by `imshow`. Such callback takes a pointer to `void` data - it enables you to pass any data you want to use when redrawing your image, in this case it should be pointer to output image (and probably a pointer to source image - you should always add new brightness level to original image, not modified one):

```
struct Params {
    cv::Mat* src;
    cv::Mat* dest;
};
void makeBrightness(int pos, void* data) {
    Params* params = (Params*)data;
    for (int i = 0; i < params->src->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < params->src->cols; j++) {
            Vec3b pixelColor;
            pixelColor = params->src->at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i));
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                if (pixelColor[k] + pos > 255)
                    pixelColor[k] = 255;
                else
                    pixelColor[k] += pos;
                params->dest->at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i)) = pixelColor;
            }
        }
    }
    imshow("Bright Image", *(params->dest));
}
int main()
{
    int brightness_value = 25; //global values
    const int max_value = 255;
    
    Mat srcImage = cv::imread("D:/lena.jpg");
    Mat brightImage;
    srcImage.copyTo(brightImage);
    namedWindow("Bright Image");
    moveWindow("Bright Image", 300, 600);
    Params params;
    params.src = &srcImage;
    params.dest = &brightImage;
    createTrackbar("Brightness", "Bright Image", &brightness_value, max_value, makeBrightness, &params);
    makeBrightness(brightness_value, &params); // for first painting your image
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know there should be a callback function for this, lesson learned. :) Everything now works as I wanted it to.